# Modelling two series with standard deviation levels

Tags: vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

Hi I will try to build a variance modelling survey for two variables. First the VIX, second XAU/USD. Standard deviations of my variables are 0.07 and 0.009 consequently (logarithmic differenced series). I will took all other diagnostic procedures for VAR and VECM modelling but do you think as a context, they are suitable series to apply a multivariate analysis

Comment: Do you have series of realized variances (and perhaps realized covariance) or just the VIX and XAU/USD themselves? If the latter, why don't you try multivariate GARCH? Because VAR and VEC models are for conditional mean, not conditional variances.

Comment: I have  themselves. Unfortunately XAU/USD's time dependent heteroskedascity test refered that it has no ARCH component. So I thougth 
 a multivariate GARCH modelling would be problematic.

Comment: So what is there to model then? What do you really want to achieve?